# fibonacci function in scheme

Tags: python, scheme, fibonacci

I'm trying to convert a fibonacci function from python to scheme,

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

to

```
(define (fib n)
    (if (= n 1)
         0)
    (if (= n 2)
         1)
    (+ fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))
```

I get error here because apparently scheme requires an `else` statement. However, as a novice scheme learner, I can't figure out how to make it with an else statement. Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: Your definition of the Fibonacci sequence is wrong: fib(0)=0, fib(1)=1, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: For an "one-armed `if`", see `when` and `unless`.

Comment: you can always use some throwaway value as an alternative, e.g. `(if (= n 1) 0 'nothing)`. But **only the *last* expression's value in a function is returned**, so if you have several IFs like that, only the last will count. that's why you should use *nested* IFs (or COND), to have one expression (with several branches) whose value will be thus returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some Scheme interpreters (in particular: in Racket) all `if` expressions must have two parts: consequent and alternative (the `else` part). So to fix your code, you should nest the `if` expressions like this (and notice the recommended way to indent and close the parentheses):

```
(define (fib n)
  (if (= n 1)
      0
      (if (= n 2)
          1
          (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
```

But to tell the truth, when there are more than two conditions, you should use `cond` instead of nesting `if`s, it'll be easier to write and easier to read:

```
(define (fib n)
  (cond ((= n 1) 0)
        ((= n 2) 1)
        (else (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
```

For completeness' sake: for those cases when you really, really want to use an `if` without an `else` part, you can use `when`. And a bit of nitpicking: the usual way to define `fibonacci` is to return `0` if `n` is `0`, and to return `1` if `n` is `1`; as it is your implementation will return incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(define (fib n)
    (if (= n 1)
         0
         (if (= n 2)
             1
             (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
```

The syntax is:

```
(if predicate consequent alternative)
```

such as

```
(if (> 3 2) 'yes 'no)
```

But I would recommend you to use `cond` in your case

Comment: Parentheses on a line of their own are not considered good style.

Comment: @uselpa but in this way is more easily readable and verifiable

Comment: The only thing you see "better" in this case is that you didn't forget any closing parenthesis, at the expense of 3 useless lines. But both your implementation and probably your editor will tell you that as well. The real benefit of readability is achieved through proper indentation.

Comment: @uselpa OK, I got it :) Thx for the tip, I appreciate it!